# React-native does not install with npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I run on my terminal the following command: `npm install react-native`

I got this error.

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.1.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native@0.55.4 requires a peer of react@16.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN abdu@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN abdu@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ react-native@0.55.4
updated 1 package in 22.645s
```

Can someone tell me please, how to fix this Issues? or what does mean?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: isn't it pretty clear that you are missing dependencies that you have to install yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start a project from scratch I recommend you to use create-native-app from the official react-native doc : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

`npm install -g create-react-native-app`

Then run the following commands to create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

`create-react-native-app AwesomeProject`

`cd AwesomeProject`

`npm start`

otherwise you should simply install missing peer dependancies

`npm i -S install ajv react@16.3.1`

Comment: Ok guys
Thank you very much. I will try It now with this new method.

Comment: I highly recommend you to use create-native-app as you will have other missing peer dep as eslint and so on

Comment: The Issues was that I did not Install it sudo. It is just  working including sudo. I do no why. 

Also like this:<code> sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app </code>

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Seem related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo


For me, the best way is to use NVM to manage your node and NPM install.


The other way is to give right access to npm. But I don't really like the idea to play with npm permision.

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`